# jQuery check if closest input to checkbox is empty

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a system which controls which numbers are displayed on the client side of the website.

The back end controls this, I have rules which only allow 3 numbers to be checked as well as removing and clearing these numbers.

I want to take this a step further, which is to not allow the check box to be ticked if the input field where the number is inserted is blank.

I've tried the following but with no avail or view my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HCRmQ/13/):

This code can be found on line 22 in the javascript section.

```
$("input[class='contact_no']").change(function () {    
            if( $(this).siblings('input:text').vallength == 0 ) {
               alert('Field is empty!');
            }
    });
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: what's that `vallength` ?

Comment: Why you have this $("input[class='contact_no']"); instead of $("input.contact_no")?

Comment: edit : `if( $(this).siblings('input:text').val().length == 0 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for

```
if ($(this).closest('tr').find('input:text:not([name^="telname"])').val().length == 0) {
    alert('Field is empty!');
}
```

I assume that it's the phone number field you want to check, not the one with "Tel" in it, so I changed it.

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HCRmQ/17/)**

This is a pretty messy way of selecting an input field that belongs to the current check box. Since they have increasing names (tel1, tel2, tel3, ...), we have to move up to our parent and find an input field that doesn't contain anything that starts with `telname` and so on...

If you just gave the input field for the phone number a general class, like `class="phone"`, it would be much easier to find with something like:

```
if ($(this).closest('tr').find('.phone').val().length == 0) {
    alert('Field is empty!');
}
```

**Request from comments**

Here is how you get the name of the corresponding element:

```
$("input[class='contact_no']").change(function () {
    var t = $(this).closest('tr').find("input.contactnumbersinput");
    var parameters = t.attr('name');

    if (t.val().length == 0) {
       alert('This number ' + parameters + ' is empty please insert a phone number!');
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry i meant all the phone numbers even the ones that are hidden, which can be unhidden by clicking "add" under the mobile input. i inserted a class rather than using a name but this didn't work

Comment: Added some more about an easier solution, if you just give the phone number fields a class.

Comment: thanks this is how i've implemented this in the end. very quickly if you can help I want to retrieve the name of the input box i.e. <input name="fax" value="0125456885">. so that when my alert is called back it informs you of the relevant input. I've tried the following `var parameters = $("input.contactnumbersinput:name", this).val();` however this comes back as undefined. http://jsfiddle.net/HCRmQ/20/

Comment: To get the name instead of the value, just use `.attr('name')` instead of `.val()` at the very end. Remove `:name` from the selector.

Comment: i've tried this `var parameters = $(".contactnumbersinput", this).attr('name');` this still comes back as undefined http://jsfiddle.net/HCRmQ/21/

Comment: Updated my answer again. Also, you don't need `input[class='contactnumbersinput]`. Use `input.contactnumbersinput` instead. `.` is the class selector.